# MySQL query performance which uses huge table to generate the report for a given day with the cummulative count and count

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am using MySQL and I have a detail table which consists 2 million records in my local and following query take approx 2 mins for those 2 million records to generate output but on production I have 80 million records in that table on any given day.

I already have index on column like `StatusDateTime`, `ProductionFacility` and `ProductionStatusNo` .

Even I have partition in the table based on `ProductionStatusNo` for the values like 0,1,2 and so on till 12.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `a_dashboard_count`(
IN p_StatusDate Date, 
IN p_UnassignedProductionFaciltiy nvarchar(500)
)
BEGIN

     DECLARE PD_S_C INT;
     SELECT COALESCE(cumulative_count, 0) INTO PD_S_C  FROM (   
     SELECT 0 AS dummy_value 
        ) dummy
LEFT JOIN dailysummary ON  ProductionStatusNo = 1     AND StatusDateTime = DATE_SUB(p_StatusDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    

INSERT INTO dailysummary(ProductionStatus ,ProductionStatusNo,StatusDateTime ,count , cumulative_count ) 

SELECT 'Unassigned' AS ProductionStatus,
        0 AS ProductionStatusNo, 
        p_StatusDate AS StatusDate,
       COUNT(DISTINCT d.UniqueFormId) as DayCount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT d.UniqueFormId) as CumulativeCount
FROM detail d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT UniqueFormId
    FROM detail exd
    WHERE exd.StatusDate <= p_StatusDate AND exd.ProductionStatusNo != 1
) exd ON d.UniqueFormId = exd.UniqueFormId
WHERE d.ProductionFacility = p_UnassignedProductionFaciltiy
  AND d.StatusDate <= p_StatusDate
  AND exd.UniqueFormId IS NULL
  
union all

 SELECT
    ps.Status,
    ps.Id,
    p_StatusDate,
    COALESCE(totalcount, 0) AS count,
    COALESCE(totalcount, 0) + PD_S_C AS cumulative_count
FROM
    productionstatus AS ps
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT d.UniqueFormId) AS totalcount,
        p_StatusDate AS StatusDate,
        d.ProductionStatusNo
    FROM
        detail AS d
    LEFT JOIN
        detail AS exd ON d.UniqueFormId = exd.UniqueFormId
                       AND exd.StatusDate < p_StatusDate
                       AND exd.ProductionStatusNo = d.ProductionStatusNo
    WHERE
        d.StatusDate = p_StatusDate
        AND exd.UniqueFormId IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        d.ProductionStatusNo
) AS d ON ps.Id = d.ProductionStatusNo
WHERE
    ps.Id = 1



        UNION all

        SELECT     ps.Status AS ProductionStatus,    
        ps.Id AS ProductionStatusNo,  
        p_StatusDate AS StatusDate,   
        COALESCE(c, 0)  AS  DayCount,  
        COALESCE(c, 0) AS CumulativeCount 
        FROM  productionstatus as ps
        LEFT JOIN (    SELECT         COUNT(*) as c,        ed.psn 
        FROM (
        SELECT
            UniqueFormId,MAX(productionStatusNo) as psn  FROM   detail
        WHERE   StatusDate <= p_StatusDate
        GROUP BY UniqueFormId
            ) as ed
        GROUP BY ed.psn
        ) as l ON ps.Id = l.psn
        WHERE
            ps.Id not in ( 0,1);
END
```

and here is the table schema with indexs

```
CREATE TABLE `detail` (
  `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  
 
  `EINNo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `EmployeeNo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Form` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  
  `ProductionStatusNo` int NOT NULL,
  
  
  `UniqueFormId` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  `ProductionFacility` varchar(450) NOT NULL,
  
  `StatusDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`ProductionStatusNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_EINNo` (`EINNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_EmployeeNo` (`EmployeeNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_Form` (`Form`),
  KEY `idx_detail_UniqueFormId` (`UniqueFormId`),
  KEY `idx_detail_ProductionFacility` (`ProductionFacility`),
  KEY `idx_detail_ProductionStatusNo` (`ProductionStatusNo`),
  KEY `idx_detail_StatusDate` (`StatusDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11652798 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (`ProductionStatusNo`)
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (4) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (5) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (6) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (8) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (9) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (10) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (11) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (12) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (13) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;
```

Comment: Do you really need in UNION? Does there are duplicates in combined rowset? if not then use UNION ALL. If the dups are present, and they must be removed, then use UNION ALL in all places except the last one.

Comment: please add table definitions as text, amend the query to prepend table names/alias to column names, add an explain for the query and for each of the 3 unioned queries. Sample data as text would also be nice.

Comment: 'this query takes two parameters' - is this code running in a stored procedure - please add relevant sp code.

Comment: To optimize queries like yours With a table that size you'll need to stop using VARCHAR columns to store dates, and use DATE or DATETIME. Then you need to get rid of the performance killing `DATE(column) <= constant` construct and replace it with something [sargable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). Then, optimize each arm of your UNION separately.

Comment: It's not difficult, but you gave too little information. Only SQL statement and table structure can't solve this problem perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Instead of slogging through the Fact table, build and maintain a [*Summary Table*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) containing daily subtotals.

Do you need to include the current day's counts?  (There are two ways to deal with that.)

- [*Partitioning*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) is probably useless unless you plan to delete "old" data.  Then it only helps the big delete (by using `DROP PARTITION` instead of a big `DELETE`).
- Redundant:

  ```
  KEY `idx_ProductionStatus` (`ProductionStatus`),  // DROP this
  KEY `IX_detail_Covering`   (`ProductionStatus`,`StatusDateTime`,`Id`),
  ```
- Why do you select this twice:

  ```
  COUNT(DISTINCT UniqueFormId )
  ```
- Please qualify each column with the table it comes from.  I am having trouble interpreting this:

  ```
  WHERE  DATE(statusdatetime) <= p_StatusDateTime
  ```

  Furthermore, `DATE(col)` is not [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) .  Maybe we can fix it.

  And, I can't analyze the indexes without the aliases.
- You are using `LEFT JOIN`, but not checking for `NULL`.  Perhaps a plain `JOIN` is more appropriate?
- I don't think the `COALESCE` is needed in this situation:

  ```
  COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) as c
  ```
- `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` is often very inefficient.  Try

  ```
  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ... )
  ```

  or

  ```
  LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL
  ```
- *AND* Good grief; store datetime values in `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, *NOT* `VARCHAR`.
- In some situations, temp tables can sometimes be avoided by using CTEs (in 8.0 or 10.2).
- These indexes *may* help with performance:

  ```
  exd:  INDEX(StatusDate, ProductionStatusNo, UniqueFormId)
  d:    INDEX(StatusDate, UniqueFormId, ProductionStatusNo)
  d:    INDEX(ProductionFacility, StatusDate, UniqueFormId)
  ```

  and DROP any indexes that match the left part(s), such as `KEY idx_detail_StatusDate (StatusDate)`

Comment: Instead of slogging through the Fact table, build and maintain a Summary Table containing daily subtotals. the problem is this process runs every day for the dump in detail table and in that dataset there will be rows where data have new status for old dates. so not sure how daily summary will help  ? can you help me more on that part

Comment: @rahularyansharma - OK, that gets tricky.  If the number of rows with "old dates" is relatively small, it may be practical to lookup the old values and adjust the subtotals.  (If large, it won't be practical.)

Comment: and that's why I need to run this stored procedure for all previous dates also to adjust  the count  , current stored procedure mentioned in question is taking date as parameter . Thanks

Comment: Make some of the recommended changes, and I will make another stab at optimizing the query.

Comment: updated the question further with the latest updated I made so far , also can you help me on how I can use temporary tables in this solution to store any information which is redudent in nature in those three queries ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma - Which version of MySQL?  If 8.0, then read up on CTEs

Comment: which part of my query can be improved with the use of CTEs ? I used CTEs in MS SQL Server earlier in the past.

Comment: @rahularyansharma - I added some indexes